# Prove if $A\Delta B\subseteq A\Delta C$ then $A\cap C\subseteq B\subseteq A\cup C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm a bit stuck on the following problem:

> Prove if $A\Delta B\subseteq A\Delta C$ then $A\cap C\subseteq B\subseteq A\cup C$.

At first, I write the statement like that:
$$(A\Delta B\subseteq A\Delta C)\implies(A\cap C\subseteq B)\land(B\subseteq A\cup C)$$
And then handle the two parts separated by $\land$ independently. On each part I use proof by contradiction, so I will try to prove the two following statements:

I. $A\cap C\not\subseteq B$

II. $B\not\subseteq A\cup C$

In case of $A\cap C\not\subseteq B$:

It means that every $x$ will meet the requirement of $(x\in A)\land(x\in C)\land(x\not\in B)$.

Now there is the problem that I can't understand how to proceed from here. I know that I should find a statement which conflicts with the *if* requirement, but it looks tricky.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I. is true, then there is some element $x$ such that $x \in A \cap C$ and $x \notin B$. Then $x \in A \triangle B$ but $x \notin A \triangle C$.

---

If II. is true, then there exists some $x$ such that $x \in B$ and $x \notin A$ and $x \notin C$. Then $x \in A \triangle B$ but $x \notin A \triangle C$.

Answer (score 2):

$A\cap C\not\subseteq B$ means that *there exists* such an $x$, and not for all $x$, that doesn't make sense.

So, assume $x\in A,\ x\in C,\ x\notin B$. Then we have $x\in A\triangle B$ while $x\notin A\triangle C$.

Can you similarly do the other case?

Comment: Yes, the other case looks pretty easy now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in A\cap C$, then $x\in A \land A\in C$.

Therefore $x\not\in A\ominus C$, therefore (by $A\ominus B\subseteq A\ominus C$), $x\not\in A\ominus B$.

Therefore $x\in B$, because if $x\not\in B$,then  $x\in A\ominus B$, which is a contradiction.

---

If $x\in B$, and $x\not\in A \land x\not\in C$, then $x\in A\ominus B \land x\not\in A\ominus C$, which is a contradiction.

### ----

I came up with this proof later on.

We construct the truth table for the Boolean variables $A,B,C$, and calculate $A\otimes B, A\otimes C$, where $X\otimes Y$ is $X$ XOR $Y$.

This is the same as sets in that $x\in A, x\in B, x\not\in C$ is the same as saying $A=1, B=1, C=0$. All possibilities are covered.

The truth table looks like:

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A&B&C&A\otimes B&A\otimes C\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&1&1\\
1&0&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&0&1\\
1&1&1&0&0\\
\hline
\end{array}

The definition of subset is that:

$X\subset Y \implies (x\in X \implies x\in Y)$

and corresponds to the truth table:

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|}
\hline
X&Y&X \subset Y\\
\hline
0&0&1\\
0&1&1\\
1&0&0\\
1&1&1\\
\hline
\end{array}

which is to say that if $X\le Y$ then the SUBSET relation holds, otherwise it doesn't.

The only two lines for $A\ominus B\not\subset A\ominus C$ are:

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A&B&C&A\otimes B&A\otimes C\\
\hline
0&1&0&1&0\\
1&0&1&1&0\\
\hline
\end{array}

So, as we are given the SUBSET relation, if $x\in B$, then $x\in A \lor A\in C$ (because if in neither, the SUBSET relation fails). Therefore $B\subseteq A\cup C$.

And also, if $x\in A\land C$, then it must be in $B$, otherwise the SUBSET relation fails. Therefore $A\cap C\subset B$.

### ----

And another:

If $X$ and $Y$ are Boolean variables, then the value of $X$ **XOR** $Y$ is given by this formula.

$X\otimes Y=X+Y-2XY$

We have been told:

$A\otimes B\subseteq A\otimes C$

$A\otimes B\le A\otimes C$

which translates to:

$A+B-2AB\le A+C-2AC$

$B(1-2A)\le C(1-2A)$

This is simplified by considering either $A=0$ or $A=1$, to give:

$A=0: B\le C$

$A=1: C\le B$.

For the rest, we need formula for **AND** and **OR**, which are:

$X\land Y=XY$

$X\lor Y=X+Y-XY$

So we need to prove:

1. $AC\le B$

and

2. $B\le A+C-AC$

These follow easily by using the two cases for $A$.

1. $A=0$ gives $0\le B$, which is always true. $A=1$ gives $C\le B$, which is confirmed by the formula.
2. $A=0$ reduces to $B\le C$, which is true by the formula for $A=0$. $A=1$ reduces to $B\le A(=1)$, which is always true.

Comment: Nice one! But you must fix the formatting in the beginning of the later proof

Comment: @Dave93; thnx, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

$A-B$ = $A\cap B^c$ (property1)

---

So we are given that (using property 1)

($A\cap B^c$) $\cup$ ($B\cap A^c$) $\subseteq$ ($A\cap C^c$) $\cup$ ($C\cap A^c$)

Obviously $A\cap B^c$ and $C\cap A^c$ have no elements common , similarly $B\cap A^c$ and $A\cap C^c$ also have no element common ($A$ and $A^c$ cannot have a common element )

It can be concluded $A\cap B^c$ $\subseteq$ $A\cap C^c$ ....(i) and also $B\cap A^c $ $\subseteq$ $C\cap A^c$.....(ii)

---

Now if $L \ \subseteq M$ implies $M^c \ \subseteq \ L^c$ (property 2)

We will use this property on (i) and (ii)

---

Hence we have

($A\cap C^c$)$^c \ \subseteq$  ($A\cap B^c$)$^c$ and do the same with the second one

---

Using de morgan's rule we have

$ A^c \cup C$  $\subseteq$ $A^c \cup B$ , now obviously

$C-A^c$ $\subseteq \ B$ , because these elements cannot be found in $A^c$

Using property 1 we have  $C\cap A$ $\subseteq$ $B$

---

If you repeat similar prodecure to second , you will end with 
$C^c-A$ $\subseteq$ $B^c$ .

So we have $C^c\cap A^c$ $\subseteq$ $B^c$

Using property 2

$B$ $\subseteq$ ($A^c\cap C^c$)$^c$

Again using de morgan's rule

We have $B$ $\subseteq$ ($A\cup C$)